# Node.js having trouble updating items in file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm having troubles updating my users, my goal is to continuously add points to a user every x amount of seconds. Every time it goes through the loop, it is only adding the 10 points to the last user even though I go through each user in the loop... Any help would be appreciated!

```
setInterval(function(){            
        var fs = require("fs");
        var data = fs.readFileSync('updatedPoints.txt', 'utf-8');
        fs.readFile("updatedPoints.txt", {encoding: "utf8"}, function(error, data){
        var i = 0;
        var currentUser = "";
        //Reads until nothing left in the file
        while(data[i] != null){                 
            currentUser += data[i]
            i++;
        }
        var splitUsers = currentUser.split(",");
        for(var i = 0; i < splitUsers.length - 1; i++){
            //Splits up the name right until the first bracket which holds the users current points
            var name = String(splitUsers[i].match(/^[^\(]+/g));     
            //Gets the users points         
            var userPoints = Number(splitUsers[i].match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]);                 
            console.log(name);
            console.log(userPoints);                                                
            var test = userPoints + 10;
            var newValue = data.replace(name+"("+userPoints+")", name+"("+test+")");
            fs.writeFileSync('updatedPoints.txt', newValue, 'utf-8');
            console.log('readFileSync complete');                    
        }
    });
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: I think you are overwriting the file for each call to `fs.writeFileSync` the docs say it: "writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists. data can be a string or a buffer."

Comment: Try changing the var to a let in the line e.g.
        for(let i = 0; i < splitUsers.length - 1; i++){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reset data value after data.replace,
like that

```js
var newValue = data.replace ...

data = newValue
```

because string.replace can't reset string directly